# Workaround for nested MySQL query?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

**The following pieces of code are pseudo - there is nothing wrong with the database structure. I am working with a Database First approach and they already proved to work fine.**

Consider the following tables;

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }       
}
```

And say I want to grab all `Blogs` in which a user has posted twice (or more).
Considering `MyDbContext` is a `DbContext`, I would do this;

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext)
{
    var doublePosters = context.Blog.Where(b => b.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.UserName).Any(x => x.Count() > 1));
    foreach(var poster in doublePosters)
    {
        //Do things with it
    }
}
```

In turn, since I am using EF6 and a MySQL database, the `IQueryable<>` will look like this;

```
SELECT `Extent1`.`Id`, `Extent1`.`Content` 
FROM `Blog` AS `Extent1`
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 AS `C1`
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT
        `Extent2`.`UserName` AS `K1`, COUNT(1) AS `A1`
        FROM `Post` AS `Extent2`
        WHERE `Extent1`.`Id` = `Extent2`.`BlogId`
        GROUP BY `Extent2`.`UserName`
        ) AS `GroupBy1`
    WHERE `GroupBy1`.`A1` > 1
 )
```

However, MySQL does not handle this well as it returns

> SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'Extent1.Id' in 'where clause'

I already figured this is a limitation from MySQL, and therefore I my question is **how can I achieve the same result without hitting the database very hard?**

An option is, ofcourse, to query the whole `Blog` table, put it in a `List<>` and let LINQ do the rest. However, my `Blog` table consists of ~500000 records - not a good idea to get *all* of them.

**EDIT**

Some sample data and expected data;

Blog:

```
+----+---------+
| Id | Content |
+----+---------+
| 1  | "blabla"|
| 2  | "albalb"|
+----+---------+
```

Post:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| BlogId | UserName | Content |
+--------+----------+---------+
| 1      |  Jon     | "Nice!" |
| 1      |  Jon     | "Well.."|
| 1      |  Jon     | "Nvm."  |
| 1      |  Sam     | "Ok!"   |
| 1      |  Sam     | "Good." |
| 1      |  Robert  | "Sweet" |
| 2      |  Robert  | "Nah"   |
| 2      |  Jonah   | "Hey"   |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Expected output from the query:

```
+----+---------+
| Id | Content |
+----+---------+
| 1  | "blabla"|
+----+---------+
```

Since only `Blog` 1 has a poster who posted multiple times (looking at you, Jon and Sam).

Comment: Could you share some sample data and expected output from that sample data ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it feets your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this approach (split the query in two parts)?

```
var posts= context.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.UserName).Any(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(y=>y.BlogId).ToList(); 
var doublePosters = context.Blog.Where(b=> posts.Contains(b.Id)); 
foreach(var poster in doublePosters) {
            //Do things with it 
}
```

I'm not sure about the performance of this approach (code not tested), maybe it could be a starting point for a new way to solve the problem.

What I would to suggest is

1. Get all id of the blog where someone has posted more than once.
2. Filter blogs by Ids of the previous query

**update**

try this code to achieve your goal

```
var postIds = context.Posts.GroupBy(p => new {p.BlogId,p.UserName}).Where(x=> x.Count() > 1).Select(el=> el.Key.BlogId);
var doublePosters = context.Blog.Where(b => postIds.Contains(b.Id)).ToList();
```

the key is to group by BlogId and UserName

Comment: Wouldn't this approach mean that, given the example in my edit, in this case `Blog` 2 will also be returned since `Posts.GroupBy(p => p.UserName)` will group, for example, `Robert` with a count of 2?

Comment: I haven't change your first query, if your first output was correct Now it is still good

Comment: but I suppose that from this query blog 2 will put in output.. give me 5 minutes to change the query

Comment: Well, not really, since I query `Blog.Where()` that means I will get all the posts which are joined with `Blog`, meaning I `GroupBy()` over a given `BlogId`. If I use `GroupBy()` on the whole `Posts` table and group it by the `UserName`, taking the `Count()` will result in a *total* amount of posts made over *all* blogs - not what I am looking for, unfortunately.

Comment: Yup! This one seems to work, even though the query takes somewhat long because `Posts` has over 1 million entries - but I can fix that by paging. Also, I added `Distinct()` at the end, to eliminate duplicates. Thanks!